# Microsoft.Office.Word.Interop Deleting comments

Tags: c#

Here is the part of my code that I need help with:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= doc2.Comments.Count; i++)
            {


                Console.WriteLine(doc2.Comments[i].Author);
                Console.WriteLine(doc2.Comments[i].Range.Text);
                Console.WriteLine("The number of comments is: " + doc2.Comments.Count);
                var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Ignore", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
                Console.WriteLine("Regex result is " + regex.IsMatch(doc2.Comments[i].Range.Text).ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Content is : '" + doc2.Comments[i].Range.Text+"'");

                if (regex.IsMatch(doc2.Comments[i].Range.Text))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting a comment that reads - '" + doc2.Comments[i].Range.Text + "'");

                    doc2.Comments[i].Range.Delete();
                    doc2.Comments[i].Scope.Delete();
                    doc2.Comments[i].DeleteRecursively();
                }

            }
```

I have a program that adds comments to a word document, I used a macro to add a comment called "Ignore" when my program can see this comment I wish for all associated comments to be deleted.
So far it deletes most the comments but not all, I've tried using different ways to delete to see if that works but nothing has helped me progress further.
Any help would be much appreciated.